# C# Replicate This Code - JSON with Object with JSON

Tags: c#, json, object

I'm relatively new to C# and I'm looking to replicate this following JSON expression:

```
{"itemData":[{"pile":"club","id":"100997087277"}]}
```

At present I have the following methods:

```
public class MoveItemValues
{
    public string pile;
    public Int64 id;
}

public class MoveItemRequestValues
{
    public MoveItemValues itemData;
}

internal string moveItem(Int64 itemId, string pile)
{
    string moveItemResponse;
    MoveItemRequestValues bodyContent = new MoveItemRequestValues();
    bodyContent.itemData = new MoveItemValues();
    bodyContent.itemData.pile = pile;
    bodyContent.itemData.id = itemId;
    string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyContent);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonContent);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonContent);
}
```

This produces:

```
"{"itemData":{"pile":"trade","id":100997087277}}"
```

But as you can see the square brackets are missing.

How would I go about finishing off achieving this?

Comment: I think itemData needs to be an array of MoveItemValues.

Comment: @JakobOlsen Or a `List<MoveItemValues>`.

Comment: FYI the accepted style in C# is to use aliases like `long` instead of `Int64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**itemData** is an **array** in the json string.

**FYI:** You need to follow the C# naming guidelines. Property and method should be Pascal case.

```
public class MoveItemValues
{
    public string Pile;
    public Int64 Id;
}

public class MoveItemRequestValues
{
    public IList<MoveItemValues> ItemData;

    public MoveItemRequestValues()
    {
        ItemData = new List<MoveItemValues>();
    }
}

static void MoveItem(Int64 itemId, string pile)
{
    string moveItemResponse;
    MoveItemRequestValues bodyContent = new MoveItemRequestValues();
    bodyContent.ItemData = new List<MoveItemValues>()
    {
        new MoveItemValues {Pile = pile, Id = itemId}
    };
    var camelCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyContent, camelCaseFormatter);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonContent);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonContent);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MoveItem(100997087277, "trade");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Won't that change the casing in the Json string as well?

Comment: I updated the answer which uses **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver**

Comment: Very nice the only thing I would change is `Int64` to `long`.

Comment: @juharr Thank you for pointing out the casing. I also agree on changing **Int64** to **long**.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the advice on naming guidelines - always been habit to camel case in ColdFusion! Also, updated Int64 to long. Is there any particular reason why to use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Use List<>

```
public class MoveItemRequestValues
{
    public List<MoveItemValues> itemData;
}
```

Comment: You should also show how the `moveItem` method needs to change.